# Ошибка в ответе, который выдает программа

Tags: python

Система, принимающая задачи, не принимает мое решение, выдает ошибку. Не могу понять, что не так. Программа запускается нормально.
P.S. в исходном варианте программы у меня в первой строке написано def task2() и task2() в конце, здесь это не записал. Заранее благодарю.

'''

```
n = int(input())
commands = {}

for i in range(n):
    command, score = input().split("\t")
    command1, command2 = command.split('-')
    score1, score2 = map(int, score.split(':'))
    if command1 not in commands:
        commands[command1] = [0, 0, 0]
    if command2 not in commands:
        commands[command2] = [0, 0, 0]

    commands[command1][0] += score1 # Забили
    commands[command2][0] += score2 
    commands[command1][1] += score2 # Пропустили
    commands[command2][1] += score1
    # Очки
    if score1 == score2:
        commands[command1][2] += 1 
        commands[command2][2] += 1
    elif score1 < score2:
        commands[command2][2] += 3
    elif score1 > score2:
        commands[command1][2] += 3

def func1(item):
    return commands[item][2]

def func2(item):
    return commands[item][0]

def func3(item):
    return commands[item][0] - commands[item][1]

commands_list = list(commands.keys())
commands_list.sort()
commands_list.sort(key=func3, reverse=True)
commands_list.sort(key=func2, reverse=True)
commands_list.sort(key=func1, reverse=True)

for command in commands_list:
    win, lose, score = commands[command]
    print(f"{command}\t{score}\t{win}:{lose}")
```

'''

[image: задача]

Comment: Т.е. какую ошибку вы получаете, в каком месте программы, что за загадочная "система принимающая задачи", как именно она вас "не принимает" и пр. -  мы должны догадаться самостоятельно. А еще  - и дописать вашу программу, запустить ее и проверить. Чудесно!

Answer (score 1):

Дело, как минимум, в неверном порядке сортировки. Сортировки по `func3` и `func2` необходимо поменять местами: вначале сортировать по забитым мячам, и лишь потом по разнице мячей

```py
commands_list.sort() 
commands_list.sort(key=func2, reverse=True)  # забито
commands_list.sort(key=func3, reverse=True)  # разница по мячам
commands_list.sort(key=func1, reverse=True)
```